# window.location is not working second time

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following code in a form with a captcha. If the captcha is correct, then `$success = 1`, else `$success=2`. If captcha is not filled, then `$success=1`.

`id=validation` is mentioned with the captcha which is at the very bottom of the page and `id=success` is mentioned with a div element which is at the very top of the page.

**Problem :**

*First test :*
1) captcha is correct -> hit submit -> page comes to the top

*Second test :*
1) captcha is not correct or not filled -> hit submit -> page comes to the bottom
2) captcha is correct -> hit enter -> page stay in bottom
(whereas it should go to the top)

**Java Script :**

```js
var myVariable = <?php echo(json_encode($success)); ?>;
if (myVariable == 2) {
    window.location = (""+window.location).replace(/#[A-Za-z0-9_]*$/,'')+"#validation"
};
if (myVariable == 3) {
    window.location = (""+window.location).replace(/#[A-Za-z0-9_]*$/,'')+"#validation"
};
if (myVariable == 1) {
    window.location = (""+window.location).replace(/#[A-Za-z0-9_]*$/,'')+"#success"
};
```

Comment: try `window.location.href`.

Comment: have you captured the enter button event? are you receiving the request when hitting enter button

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myVariable = <?php echo(json_encode($success)); ?>;
if (myVariable == 2 || myVariable == 3) {
window.location.href = (""+window.location.href).replace(/#[A-Za-z0-9_]*$/,'')+"#validation"
};
if (myVariable == 1) {
window.location.href = (""+window.location.href).replace(/#[A-Za-z0-9_]*$/,'')+"#success"
};
</script>
```

I changed **window.location** to **window.location.href** and took the same result in one if statement.